# Get records by checking dataset values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

```
       group
+---------+-------+
| group   | limit |
+---------+-------+
| group 1 | 100   |
| group 2 | 150   |
| group 3 | 200   |
+-----------------+

     customer
+---------+------+
| name   | price |
+---------+------+
| name 1 | 90    |
| name 2 | 100   |
| name 3 | 190   |
+----------------+
```

I need to assign a `group` to a `customer` (only one `group` for each `customer`) looking at the `price` and the `limit`

#### Examples:

1. customer `name 1` can be assigned to `group 1` because `price` is less than or equal to the `limit`.
2. Customer `name 2` cannot be assigned to `group 1` because `price` is less than or equal to the `limit` but the limit has already been used by customer `name 1` in this case it has to be assigned to `group 2`

#### Expected results:

```
+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| name    | price | group   | limit |
+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| name 1  |  90   | group 1 | 100   |
| name 2  |  100  | group 2 | 150   |
| name 3  |  190  | group 3 | 200   |
+-----------------+---------+-------+
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop and do these checks and return the data in a single DataSet?

After executing the query, the application will update the `limit` by subtracting what has already been used until it reaches 0 or the lowest possible value.

Comment: So, for the data you have provided, what would be your expected results? I don't follow the logic here I am afraid.

Comment: Also, you stat in example 1 that `name 1` ***can*** be assigned as 90 is less than or equal to 100, but then go on to say that `name 2` ***can't*** be assigned as 100 is less than or equal to 100. Why is the logic different? Both 90 and 100 are less than or equal to 100, so why is one true and the other not?

Comment: Hi @Larnu! The logic is different because the limit 100 `group 1` has already been set to customer `name 1` and its new value will be 10 after the update and 10, this is the difference.

Comment: Subtracting `price` from `limit` is never even mentioned in your question though... Seems like you really need to elaborate here. *Perhaps* a windowed aggregate will help but those are only available in supported versions of SQL Server.